# Any easy way to use grsync with shared folder

Tags: networking, mount, nautilus, samba, grsync

Grsync does not browse to a source path for a shared folder on a local network PC.  I have read about setting up a mount for a shared folder and have succeeded in the past in doing this.  But it seems like hard work.  I want to be able to sync easily from my desktop PC which has some SAMBA shares to a laptop.  Grsync looks perfect but its interface does not seem to support setting the path to a shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is a partial solution using PCManFM. My portable machine is a 10 year old netbook so it is running the lightweight Ubuntu derived Bodhi 5 os which has PCManFM as its default file manager.  I discovered that the following works:

1 Open PCManFM

2 Navigate to network share (which in my case is on Ubuntu Bionic Desktop PC)

3 Left click to open shared network folder for browsing

4 Right click in navigation panel offers: "Open in terminal window" - select this

5 Terminal window shows (what to me was unlikely) path on the status line:

"USERNAME@COMPUTERNAME:/run/user/USERIDNUMBER/gvfs/smb-share:server=PCNAME,share=SHAREDFOLDERNAME$"

6 Copy to clipboard path from the terminal window ie: /run/user/USERIDNUMBER/gvfs/smb-share:server=PCNAME,share=SHAREDFOLDERNAME

7 Launch Grsync and paste path into source, edit for subfolders if desired

8 Save the session for future use in Grsync

---

I just noticed that it may be possible to do something similar on Bionic.  While I have been unable to use Nautilus to browse folder = /run/user it is possible to use a terminal in Bionic and cd /run/user

From here one can "ls" to list and see the subfolders to drill down to the name of the SAMBA share as mounted.  This seems to provide a copy and paste approach to using Grsync with network folders.